# Choose file dialog errors

Tags: c++, openfiledialog

I took this code off the internet. however, i keep getting the same errors over and over again whenever i find open file dialog codes. all of them are the same error and it's really annoying.

```
int choosefile() {
char filename[MAX_PATH];

OPENFILENAME ofn;
ZeroMemory(&filename, sizeof(filename));
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = NULL;  
ofn.lpstrFilter = L"Text Files\0*.txt\0Any File\0*.*\0";
ofn.lpstrFile = filename;
ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
ofn.lpstrTitle = L"Select a File, yo!";
ofn.Flags = OFN_DONTADDTORECENT | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

if (GetOpenFileNameA(&ofn))
{
    std::cout << "You chose the file \"" << filename << "\"\n";
}
else
{
    switch (CommDlgExtendedError())
    {
    case CDERR_DIALOGFAILURE: std::cout << "CDERR_DIALOGFAILURE\n";   break;
    case CDERR_FINDRESFAILURE: std::cout << "CDERR_FINDRESFAILURE\n";  break;
    case CDERR_INITIALIZATION: std::cout << "CDERR_INITIALIZATION\n";  break;
    case CDERR_LOADRESFAILURE: std::cout << "CDERR_LOADRESFAILURE\n";  break;
    case CDERR_LOADSTRFAILURE: std::cout << "CDERR_LOADSTRFAILURE\n";  break;
    case CDERR_LOCKRESFAILURE: std::cout << "CDERR_LOCKRESFAILURE\n";  break;
    case CDERR_MEMALLOCFAILURE: std::cout << "CDERR_MEMALLOCFAILURE\n"; break;
    case CDERR_MEMLOCKFAILURE: std::cout << "CDERR_MEMLOCKFAILURE\n";  break;
    case CDERR_NOHINSTANCE: std::cout << "CDERR_NOHINSTANCE\n";     break;
    case CDERR_NOHOOK: std::cout << "CDERR_NOHOOK\n";          break;
    case CDERR_NOTEMPLATE: std::cout << "CDERR_NOTEMPLATE\n";      break;
    case CDERR_STRUCTSIZE: std::cout << "CDERR_STRUCTSIZE\n";      break;
    case FNERR_BUFFERTOOSMALL: std::cout << "FNERR_BUFFERTOOSMALL\n";  break;
    case FNERR_INVALIDFILENAME: std::cout << "FNERR_INVALIDFILENAME\n"; break;
    case FNERR_SUBCLASSFAILURE: std::cout << "FNERR_SUBCLASSFAILURE\n"; break;
    default: std::cout << "You cancelled.\n";
    }
}
```

}

Here is the code and it's giving me an error at:

```
    ofn.lpstrFile = filename;

a value of type "char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "LPWSTR"
Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'char [260]' to 'LPWSTR'
```

Then it's giving me another error at:

```
    if (GetOpenFileNameA(&ofn))

argument of type "OPENFILENAME *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPOPENFILENAMEA"
Error   C2664   'BOOL GetOpenFileNameA(LPOPENFILENAMEA)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'OPENFILENAME *' to 'LPOPENFILENAMEA'
```

I'm getting two errors on each line of code, it really makes no sense to me and its annoying as hell. I keep getting these same errors on every that has to do with opening a dialog and letting a user select a file. it's not as simple as C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you decided to use `char` array to receive the path and `GetOpenFileNameA()` function, so `OPENFILENAMEA` structure should be used.

```
OPENFILENAME ofn;
ZeroMemory(&filename, sizeof(filename));
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = NULL;  
ofn.lpstrFilter = L"Text Files\0*.txt\0Any File\0*.*\0";
ofn.lpstrFile = filename;
ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
ofn.lpstrTitle = L"Select a File, yo!";
ofn.Flags = OFN_DONTADDTORECENT | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
```

should be

```
OPENFILENAMEA ofn;
ZeroMemory(&filename, sizeof(filename));
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = NULL;  
ofn.lpstrFilter = "Text Files\0*.txt\0Any File\0*.*\0";
ofn.lpstrFile = filename;
ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
ofn.lpstrTitle = "Select a File, yo!";
ofn.Flags = OFN_DONTADDTORECENT | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
```

(add `A` to the structure name and remove `L` prefix from the strings)